# How to enable hardware virtualization? Config change won't stick

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

...cleaning up my post...making it more clear...

I am trying to turn ON Virtualization Technology. My MB does support it
and it even shows it now as *Enabled in the BIOS*. Although once I boot to Windoes 10.
Everything there says it is **NOT turned on**.

This is what I did:

1. Turn ON the System.
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> key at startup to enter BIOS Setup.
3. Press the right arrow key to Advanced tab,
   Select Virtualization Technology and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
4. Select Enabled and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
5. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key and select Yes and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to save changes and Reboot into Windows.

My PC specification is:

- OS: Windows 10 PRO
- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700K
- Mainboard: ASUS PRIME Z270-A

I am running the *latest* BIOS.
What could be wrong?

Why would it show as **ENABLED** in the BIOS, but **DISABLED** once inside Windows?